# Failing to convert string do datetime pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, utc

I'm trying to perform de following operation:

```
pd.to_datetime('2023-05-02 11:52:09.000000 UTC', format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

But i'm getting the error: time data 2023-05-02 11:52:09.000000 UTC doesn't match format specified

Does anybody know how can I fix it?

Comment: Don't provide a format, pandas is smart enough to read this automatically: `pd.to_datetime('2023-05-02 11:52:09.000000 UTC')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mozway correctely pointed out in the comment to your question, you can write just

```
pd.to_datetime('2023-05-02 11:52:09.000000 UTC')
```

and pandas corretely convert your date. If you want to write this more explicitly, you can do this

```
pd.to_datetime('2023-05-02 11:52:09.000000', format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f', utc=True)
```

or this

```
pd.to_datetime('2023-05-02 11:52:09.000000 UTC', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z')
```

All these expressions give the same result.